# Tomcat 6 using wrong SSL cert

Tags: iis, ssl, tomcat, ssl-certificate

I have IIS and Tomcat 6 running on the same box, both applications need SSL (on different ports).  I have purchased and installed two SSL certs, one for IIS and one for Tomcat.  Both certs are using the same FQDN.  IIS is working properly, but when I try hit Tomcat, it's serving me the IIS cert and my browser is throwing a certificate revoked error.  What can I do to fix this?

IIS 7 / Win2k8 - SSL running on port 443
Tomcat 6 - SSL running on port 8443

Tomcat has its own keystore defined in the server.xml file, but that doesn't seem to be helping.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any way for it to serve up the IIS cert until IIS has a site listening on port 8443. And if the cert is revoked, you should be getting the same error when accessing it with port 443. Are you sure it is the same cert? Also check for a keystore file at "C:\Documents and Settings\user_name\". That is the default location that Tomcat will look for a keystore if the server.xml file isn't configured correctly.